# Java - Command Line Parsing a Variable Name with Value

Tags: java, command-line

In Java I am trying to read in a command line argument of the form "-p3". For instance "-p3" would tell me two pieces of information. "p" would distinguish the type of variable let's say "people". "3" would distinguish how many of the variable to instantiate the variable. So "-p3" in the command line of our program is telling us we have three people.

I'm confused how to separate the "p" from the "3". There's no character like a comma to use .split().

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the other methods that ``String`` offers.

Comment: Either use a dedicated library for command line parsing (Google is your friend) or split after the first character.

Comment: maybe apache commons-cli can ease your pain.... https://commons.apache.org/cli/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
...
String firstArgument = args[0];
if(firstArgument.charAt(1)=='P') {
  int amount=Character.getNumericValue(firstArgument.charAt(2));
  for (int i=0; i<amount;i++){
    //Initialize valid object and maybe saving it in an list/array
    ...
  }
}
...
```

Comment: You will want to do better input validation. I believe the above with arg `-p10` will yield 1, with arg `Spot` it will crash your program with a `NumberFormatException` (all provided you use a small p as in the question).

Comment: As you can see in my answer its omitting previous code as indicated by "...". I am very well aware that this is not a 100% bullet proof answer. It should just function as an idea for the asker ;)

Comment: And jup my code also just allows one digit amounts, which of course could be easily dealt with if you would see the number behind the "P" as an String instead of a mere character. But as I said, it should just give an idea and not the entire solution coded for the asker. ;)

Comment: Good point. So let my comment be a reminder for the asker too (maybe even an unnecessary one, I might hope :-)

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to criticize (as I did in a comment to the other answer). Let’s be constructive about it:

```
    final String peopleArg = "-p";
    for (String arg : args) {
        if (arg.startsWith(peopleArg)) {
            String numberAsString = peopleArg.substring(peopleArg.length());
            try {
                int noOfPeople = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
                if (noOfPeople > 0) {
                    createPeople(noOfPeople);
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Incorrect number of people to create: " + numberAsString);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect number of people to create: " + numberAsString);
            }
        }
    }
```